# How to fix user fetching from a collection in discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, collections, discord.js

I'm trying to retrieve usernames from IDs in collection (Discord.js)

I've tried fetching user with client.fetchUser(config.userID)

```
const adm = client.fetchUser(config.admins)
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setTitle("Developers")
.setDescription("Usernames: \n"+adm.username)
message.channel.send(embed);
```

It outputs "userID1,userID2 is not a snowflake"

Comment: What does config.admins contain? Is it an array of ids? or is it an object array?

Comment: config.admins contains ["userID1","userID2"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs say that the parameter should be a snowflake [Snowflake Ref](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake)

From what I can see, you are passing in an array of snowflakes which won't work.

The method returns a Promise of type User, I think you are trying to get all the users in one go.

I have created a code snip which will fetch the users one by one from your snowflake array of Admins and then create a string for you to put in your message.

Remember to use this in an ASYNC method else the `await` will throw an error.

Edit : As mentioned in the comments, you need to initialise the adminUsers before you can push to it.

```js
let adminUsers = []; // array of Users

for (let i = 0; i < config.admins.length; i++) {
  let currentUser = config.admins[i];
  let user = await client.fetchUser(currentUser);
  adminUsers.push(user);
}

let description = "Usernames: \n";

adminUsers.forEach(user => {
  description += `${user.username}\n`;
});

const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setTitle("Developers")
  .setDescription(description)
message.channel.send(embed);
```

Comment: That outputs "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Comment: @CodingLover try changing the first line from `let adminUsers;` to `let adminUsers = [];` to define it as an array.

Comment: Ok, I will try to do this.